# Pando Media Booster

Tags: media, spyware

Has anyone ran across a program "PMB.exe" labeled Pando Media Booster?

According to their website it is supposedly here to help me stream HD content.  I am trying to figure out if it is legit or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a peer-to-peer video streamer which will use your computer's network bandwidth to help other people get content.  It is safe to uninstall.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not exactly sure where it came from.  I'll rip it out and see what breaks.